# Xcode Blank App Size is 34 Mb

Tags: ios, xcode

i created new blank Xcode App and install it in my device for testing. its size become 34 Mb. if i work some, on the project it size become more large. i dont understand the problem why my app size is too large as it contains notings
  [image: this image show the size of project i have created named: sizeTestApp. this app is totally blank but is size become so large ?]

Comment: what kinda problem does the size of your app cause?

Comment: Which template did you use?

Comment: size does not cause any problem but it is to big

Comment: i am using no template it is blank app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift applications include all the linked Swift libraries.

Screenshot of two empty project applications (Swift and Objective-C):
[image: Application sizes]

Libraries (Swift):
[image]